# Flutter: When I press pause button youtube_player_iframe package shows a popup menu how to turn it off?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

When I press pause button youtube_player_iframe package shows a popup menu how to disable it. I use it on android and it doesn't show up but when I use it on ios it shows up [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9xF0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you can use youtube_player_flutter: ^8.0.0 for playing youtube videos and it is had to fix a bug with out  running a code but might this package can help you if not let me know